# Startup Error: Application cannot start in headless mode in Android Studio

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, java, jdk1.7

I am using Android Studio in Ubuntu. Few days ago I received update for Ubuntu. And I updated my OS. After that I am unable to launch android studio from desktop icon. Then I tried to to launch from terminal using this `sudo ./studio.sh` .  after this I started getting error like this.
`'tools.jar' seems to be not in Android Studio classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.` To solve this issue I set my JAVA_HOME path to jdk. Now when I try to launch android studio from terminal it shows `Startup Error: Application cannot start in headless mode` I don't know how to solve this please help.

My Java versions

`java -version`

`java version "1.7.0_95"`

`OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.4) (7u95-2.6.4-0ubuntu0.15.10.1)`

`OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.95-b01, mixed mode)`